# oAuth2 problems implementing listen function in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, oauth-2.0

I'm currently working on a quite big project. My part is it to make the mobile app, which is made with flutter (which I never used). Now the authorization of the user happens over a authorization_url from our backend.

I've implemented the oAuth2.0 for flutter according to [this example](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2/example) and I'm not quite sure how to implement the `listen` function. This is the code I have so far:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:uni_links/uni_links.dart';
import 'package:oauth2/oauth2.dart' as oauth2;
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

final authorizationEndpoint =
    Uri.parse('http://example.com/oauth2/authorization');
final tokenEndpoint = Uri.parse('http://example.com/oauth2/token');


const identifier = 'my client identifier';
const secret = 'my client secret';

final redirectUrl = Uri.parse('http://my-site.com/oauth2-redirect');

final credentialsFile = File('~/.myapp/credentials.json');

Future<oauth2.Client> createClient() async {
  var exists = await credentialsFile.exists();

  if (exists) {
    var credentials =
        oauth2.Credentials.fromJson(await credentialsFile.readAsString());
    return oauth2.Client(credentials, identifier: identifier, secret: secret);
  }

  var grant = oauth2.AuthorizationCodeGrant(
      identifier, authorizationEndpoint, tokenEndpoint,
      secret: secret);

  var authorizationUrl = grant.getAuthorizationUrl(redirectUrl);

  // `redirect` and `listen` are not shown implemented here.
  await redirect(authorizationUrl);
  var responseUrl = await listen(redirectUrl);

  return grant.handleAuthorizationResponse(responseUrl.queryParameters);
}

void authorize() async {
  var client = await createClient();

  print(client);

  await credentialsFile.writeAsString(client.credentials.toJson());
}

Future<void> redirect(Uri url) async {
  if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
    await launchUrl(url);
  }
}

// This is the code that is not working yet - 
Future<String> listen(Uri url) async {
  final linksStream = uriLinkStream.listen((Uri? uri) async {
    if (uri.toString().startsWith(url.toString())) {
      return url;
    }
  });
}
```

The listen URL, as I implemented it here gives me following error: `The return type 'Uri' isn't a 'Future<void>', as required by the closure's context`

Does somebody know what I did wrong with this function?

Answer (score 0):

The error is just telling you about type mismatch.

Namely, it'a matter of `onData()` callback, which you have specified in `listen()` method:

```
StreamSubscription<Uri?> listen(
  void Function(Uri?)? onData, {
  Function? onError,
  void Function()? onDone,
  bool? cancelOnError,
})
```

As you can see, the `listen()` method has one positional optional parameter(`onData()`), and three optional named parameters. Now we are interested only in `onData()` callback.

This callback provides us an parameter of type `Uri?`(nullable `Uri`), and expects as result `void`(NOTHING). This means, we should not return nothing in this callback, but you are trying to return an `Uri` object:

```
if (uri.toString().startsWith(url.toString())) {
  return url; // <- this line
}
```

So, what you need to do, is just to do whatever you want to do with `Uri?` object, provided in `onData()` callback inside its body, and do not try to return something in this callback, as it doesn't expect that.

P.S. do not forget to cancel the `linksStream` when you do not need it anymore.